# Declaring a quantity of lists in python dependent on function parameter

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to initialize a particular number of empty lists in a Python function; the number will depend on a parameter of the function. How do I implement this?

Comment: initialise as what? separate variables? values in a dict?  a list of them?

Comment: a list of them - preferrably I would like to be able to have some way of identifying them in the same way that declared variables can be referenced after they are initialized

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: fastest way to create a list of n lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518435/python-fastest-way-to-create-a-list-of-n-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def my_function(n):
    x = [[] for num in range(n)]
    ...
```