# NameError while using append on a list [Python]

Tags: python, python-2.7, nameerror

I'm trying to make a simple hangman game in Python 2.7.10. However when I try to append "_" for every letter in the word in a list. It throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Janek\Dropbox\python\vjesalo.py", line 82, in <module>
    append.wordlen(olo)
NameError: name 'append' is not defined
```

No idea why this happends because if I run in the python terminal

```
list = []
list.append("Bla bla bla")
```

It works just fine

Here is my code:

```
from sys import exit
from time import sleep

        word = raw_input("Enter a word: ")

        if word.isalpha() == True:
            word.lower()
        else:
            print "Invalid word!"
            sleep(3)
            exit()

        wordlen = []    
        for i in range(len(word)):
            append.wordlen("_")

        print wordlen
```

Comment: You should do it this way: `wordlen.append("_")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the call backwards

```
append.wordlen("_")
```

You meant

```
wordlen.append("_")
```

Comment: Ooooooooooh! I knew it was something silly like that. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 2):

The corrected code is

```
wordlen.append("_")
```

Another way to do it can be:

```
wordlen = ["_"]*len(word)
```

Or if you want just the string:

```
"_"*len(word)
```

Comment: `wordlen = ["_"]*len(word)` is wrong mate

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518435/python-fastest-way-to-create-a-list-of-n-lists

Answer (score 1):

It should be - `wordlen.append("_")`

list objects have the `append()` function, not the otherway round.

Answer (score 1):

You have given

```
 append.wordlen("_")
```

it should be

```
wordlen.append("_")
```