# python constantly split an array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

```
import random
i=1
a=[]
while(i<=10000):
    b=random.randint(0,9999)
    a.append(b)
    i=i+1
print(a)

def kgsorting(a):
    k=1
    sum=a[0]
    while(k<=(len(a)-1)):
        sum=sum+a[k]
        k=k+1
    avg=sum/len(a)
    return avg

#print(kgsorting(a))

def splitlist(a):
    i=0
    b=[]
    c=[]
    avg=kgsorting(a)
    while(i<=(len(a)-1)):
        if(a[i]>=avg):
            b.append(a[i])
        else:
            c.append(a[i])
        i=i+1
    return c,b


(c,b)=splitlist(a)
#print(f+g)
#g=int(input())

i=1
while(i<=1):
    (f,g)=splitlist(c)
    (h,y)=splitlist(b)
    i=i+1
flen=len(f)
glen=len(g)
hlen=len(h)
ylen=len(y)      

i=1
while(i<=flen):
    k=0
    while(k<=(flen-2)):
        if (f[k+1]<f[k]):
            temp=f[k+1]
            f[k+1]=f[k]
            f[k]=temp
        k=k+1
    i=i+1
#print(b)


i=1
while(i<=glen):
    k=0
    while(k<=(glen-2)):
        if (g[k+1]<g[k]):
            temp=g[k+1]
            g[k+1]=g[k]
            g[k]=temp
        k=k+1
    i=i+1
#print(c)
#print((c+b))


i=1
while(i<=hlen):
    k=0
    while(k<=(hlen-2)):
        if (h[k+1]<h[k]):
            temp=h[k+1]
            h[k+1]=h[k]
            h[k]=temp
        k=k+1
#print(b)


i=1
while(i<=ylen):
    k=0
    while(k<=(ylen-2)):
        if (y[k+1]<y[k]):
            temp=y[k+1]
            y[k+1]=y[k]
            y[k]=temp
        k=k+1
    i=i+1
#print(c)
print((f+g+h+y))

wer=int(input())
```

hi! i'm trying to program a sorting code in python 3.Basically i want to split an array of lets say 1000 random integers to unequal parts.The condition is if the item of the list is below or above to average of all numbers.Then i used bubble sort 4 times to sort the two lists.This sorting appears to be faster than bubblesort and  i want to split for example in 2,4,8,16,32,64...n without doing the thing i did to the code for 4 splits.Apparently the more splits the faster it is so i want n splits.I haven't found a way to do that recursively or by a loop or something.Do you have an idea what to do?
thanks
Edit:The program in the beginning make a list from random integers,then calculates the average,then splits the list a to c,b lists,then splits c to f,g and b to h,y lists.Finally i have 4 lists and i used 4 times bubble sort for every list to sort them and i merge the 4 lists at the end. Does anyone know how to do n splits to list a?

Comment: it may be easier to frame your question with the input and desired result, rather than walking us through your approach (do that by commenting the code...). Your while loop copy/paste could be a function you apply and then we could refine that further, but I am not sure I understand what you're trying to get at the end which makes it tough to advise the right approach, rather than just syntactically correct code.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive loop for doing a **n** amount of splits to list **a** would need to create 2 lists for every time you split the list. To do it, a method would be created that takes in a list and splits it into 2 parts, then calls it again for those parts.

The other way of would be to simply split the list into n amount of pieces but this would also only work if you had a n amount of lists
[Python: fastest way to create a list of n lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518435/python-fastest-way-to-create-a-list-of-n-lists) shows how to do so with

```
d = [[] for x in xrange(n)]
```

although this creates a list of lists it can be done with some work

Then to do a recursive loop you could do

```
def recursiveLoop(list, n):
    d = [[] for x in xrange(n)]
    index = 0
    while(index < len(list)/2): #splits the list
        d.append(list[index])
        index++
    recursiveLoop(d, n/2)
```

I will be checking to make sure ^^ works since at the moment I think it does not, but the idea is there, just split the list and call the same function to split it again.