# Nested loops do not print correct row number python

Tags: python-3.x

This is my first time posting to Stack Overflow. Here is my problem:

I am trying to create an array in python using list of lists. I am trying to add rows but it only shows the last row values nothing before that.

Here is my code:

```
my_list = [1] *4

blank_lst = []
for row in range (0, len(my_list)):
    blank_lst.append(my_list)


for row in range(0,len(blank_lst)):
    for col in range(0,len(blank_lst[0])):
        blank_lst[row][col] = str(row) + str(col)



print(blank_lst)
```

Output:
[['30', '31', '32', '33'], ['30', '31', '32', '33'], ['30', '31', '32', '33'], ['30', '31', '32', '33']]

[Finished in 0.1s]

P.S: I am using Sublime Text editor

Comment: What should the result be?

Comment: [['00', '01', '02', '03'], ['10', '11', '12', '13'], ['20', '21', '22', '23'], ['30', '31', '32', '33']]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I added some print in code for you:

```
my_list = [1] *4

blank_lst = []
for row in range (0, len(my_list)):
    blank_lst.append(my_list)

for lst in blank_lst:
    print(id(lst))
    for cell in lst:
        print(id(cell))

for row in range(0, len(blank_lst)):
    for col in range(0, len(blank_lst[0])):
        blank_lst[row][col] = str(row) + str(col)
        print(row, col, blank_lst)

print(blank_lst)
```

First, you may find out that all 4 printed IDs of the 4 list you append into blank_lst are same. Which means if you modify one of them, you modify all of them. All of the four lists are actually mapped into same part of memory, they are same list. That is the reason why you find the final result is not what you want.

Further more, if you check the id of every element in the sub-list of blank_lst, they are same either.

[Python: fastest way to create a list of n lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518435/python-fastest-way-to-create-a-list-of-n-lists)

This may help you to understand this phenomenon better.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the result you want.

```
blank_lst =[]
for row in range(0,4):
    blank_lst.append([str(x).zfill(2) for x in range(row*10, row*10+4)])
print(blank_lst)
```